# How to shorten line length in react-d3-tree

Tags: reactjs, tree, treeview, hierarchy, react-d3

I want to shorten the line (in red).
nodesize is set to Y:400 but when I change it to 200 the distance in red stays the same what changes is the forgeinobject card causing it to overlap with the horizental link when toggling the children nodes. what can I do here?
[image]